# php mail script works well on wamp64 localserver but does not work on the remote server

Tags: sendmail, wamp64

I've developped a simple site which features functions like sending confirmation emails, cancelling email and so forth. Very very simple.
When loading it in localhost nothing's going bad at all, as i've configured sendmail.exe on my wamp64 server, and i'm able to deliver whatever i want locally.
But once i put all may php/html stuff online on a remote Free Host via ftp, obviously i get some problems with my authomatic email sender system.
I know it is due to the remote server which could be running on Linux or simply it is not configured for running properly as the php.ini file has not been configured well.

Anyway, how can i fix it? is there any alternative to 'sendmail' which would works great on the remote Hosting server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This depends on your hosting company, so you need to ask them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question for your hosting.

Comment: I've already asked them, to no avail. Maybe they cannot do it for internal policy. To Alessandro Da Rugna, this looks like a spread issue if you do a little google all around and No, i don't want to support my Hosting. If it's just a question of changing my hosting i will do it, as soon as there's no alternative. I would prefere to stick to my actual one and fix this problem (don't want to make again the whole0 ftp loading, changing the php codes wherever's necessary and so forth...you know what i mean). Please let me know if you have any suggestion on it!